# Header correct, but identifier not found

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

I have two projects (x64).

**A**. Written in C (wxWidgets) --- edit: its in C++!

**B**. Written in C++

**A** compiles fine, but **B** (which uses functions of **A**) gives several errors when I try to compile.

I suggest that the reason for the errors is the same for all, so I mention only the first.
It says:

```
strlen: identifier not found
```

In the file which gives the error messages ( wxcrtbase.h ), the following headers are included:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>`
```

The files from **B** include the following headers from **A**:

```
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/dcbuffer.h" 
#include "wx/spinctrl.h"
```

So, currently, I have no idea where to start to search for the reason of the errors. May it be that I have C and C++ files? Maybe that I compiled for x64?

Thanks for help!

edit: more info
the lines in wxcrtbase.h around the one producing the first error message are:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus  
inline size_t wxStrlen(const char *s) { return s ? wxCRT_StrlenA(s) : 0; }  
inline size_t wxStrlen(const wchar_t *s) { return s ? wcslen(s) : 0; }
```

The order of the includes of the wxcrtbase.h is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <io.h>
```

The /showIncludes lists the following ( I stop with the list after the first two error messages ):

```
1>Compiling...
1>widget.cpp
1>Note: including file: m:\visual studio 2008\projects\general\rama\src\widget.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include \string
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\istream
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\ostream
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\ios
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xlocnum
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\climits
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\yvals.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\sal.h
1>Note: including file: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtassem.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\vadefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\use_ansi.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\limits.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstdio
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdio.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\swprintf.inl
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstdlib
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdlib.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\streambuf
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xiosbase
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xlocale
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstring
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx\string.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/defs.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/platform.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\setupp.h
1>Note: including file: m:\visual studio 2008\projects\general\wxwidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/version.h
1>Note: including file: m:\visual studio 2008\projects\general\wxwidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/cpp.h
1>Note: including file: m:\visual studio 2008\projects\general\wxwidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/cpp.h
1>Note: including file: M:/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/general/wxWidgets-2.9.0/lib/vc_lib/mswud/wx/setup.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/msw/libraries.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/chkconf.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/msw/chkconf.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/version.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/dlimpexp.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stddef.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/debug.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\assert.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file:  M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/chartype.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/platform.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\tchar.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\wchar.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\wtime.inl
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/cpp.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/windowid.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/msw/winundef.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/features.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx\string.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdarg.h
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/wxcrtbase.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\io.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cctype
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\ctype.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cwctype
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\wctype.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\ctime
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\time.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\time.inl
1>Note: including file:  M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/chartype.h
1>M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/wxcrtbase.h(705) : error C3861: 'strlen': identifier not found
1>M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/wxcrtbase.h(718) : error C3861: '_strdup': identifier not found
```

Comment: Can you post the code of B? Also please note that wxWidgets are written in C++, so if your project A uses wxWidgets I bet it is written in C++ as well.

Comment: I`m sorry, I cannot post it. Also, its just several thousand lines of code. B has includes like: #include "wx/wx.h" #include "wx/app.h"
#include "wx/frame.h"
( A. IS wxWidgets and B. is the code that uses wxWidgets )
edit: I see wxWidgets is also c++, but some files have .c endings...

Comment: edit2: even stranger: the error message comes from wxcrtbase.h. This header is not called directly by B., but obviously from another wxWidgets file.

Comment: Have you noticed that string.h is not being included? The only string.h that is being included according to your log is ...\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/cpp.h

Comment: Could it be that you have copy pasted some header file, forgot to fix the guards and the file actually doesn't get included? (I mean it does get included, but the contents are ignored) Try putting a `#warning something` right after `#include <string.h>` and see if the warning appears when compiling. If not, there is something wrong with including wxcrtbase.h

Answer (score 2):

A few things to try and/or answer:

- Can you post at least the few lines around and including the one that the compiler generates the 'identifier not found' error?
- When you say you have an `#include <string.h>` line, exactly which file(s) and does it precede the various `wx` includes?
- Can you post the output of the included headers when you build with the `/showIncludes` option (it's in the VS 2008 IDE's C++ project property page under "C/C++/Advanced/Show Includes")?

---

Edit, with new information:

Based on the edit you made that included a more complete listing from `/showIncludes`, it appears that you might have the INCLUDE path set incorrectly.  Here are a couple of lines from the log:

```
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\cstring
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx\string.h
```

When MSVC's cstring header is trying to include `string.h`, it's picking up a `string.h` header from the `wx` library instead of the one that's part of the compiler distribution (which would be in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\string.h`).

I'm not sure why the `wx` library would name one of their own headers `string.h` (instead of, say, `wxString.h`), but I assume that it's intended to be picked up by someone using something like:

```
#include "wx/string.h"
```

Regardless, I think you'll fix your problem by making sure that the MSVC include directory is in the INCLUDE search path before any other directory.

Comment: 1.
#ifdef __cplusplus
inline size_t wxStrlen(const char *s) { return s ? wxCRT_StrlenA(s) : 0; }
inline size_t wxStrlen(const wchar_t *s) { return s ? wcslen(s) : 0; }

2. the string.h is only in the wxWidgets files. There the original order is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <io.h>

3. I did what you suggested. The output is very long.
I have to do a new post for that.

Comment: Michael, thanks very much for the great help. With the MSVC directory in the first place it works now!

Answer (score 0):

If wxWidgets is C++, and it includes  and  and your compiler prevents inclusion of  and  when cstring/cstdio are included, then strlen would be in the std namespace instead of global. Try std::strlen and see if that fixes the error.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. Message: std is not a class or namespace. The headers of the wxcrtbase.h file are: "#include "wx/chartype.h" #include <stdio.h> #include <string.h> #include <ctype.h> #include <wctype.h> #include <time.h> #include <io.h>"

Comment: #include of system headers (<>) should almost always come before #include of local headers ("")

Comment: Putting the system headers in front did not change the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try `#include<cstdio>` and `#include<cstring>`, which are the headers for C++

Comment: replacing stdio.h and string.h by cstdio and cstring doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

The comment field is too small.
I answer to Michael Burr:

A.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
inline size_t wxStrlen(const char *s) { return s ? wxCRT_StrlenA(s) : 0; }
inline size_t wxStrlen(const wchar_t *s) { return s ? wcslen(s) : 0; }`
```

B. the string.h is only in the wxWidgets files.

There the original order is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <io.h>
```

C.
Here`s the some lines before and a line after the first error message:

```
1>Note: including file: M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/chartype.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\ctype.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\wctype.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\time.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\time.inl
1>Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\io.h
1>Note: including file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h
1>M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/wxcrtbase.h(696) : error C3861: 'strlen': identifier not found
1>M:\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\general\wxWidgets-2.9.0\include\wx/wxcrtbase.h(709) : error C3861: '_strdup': identifier not found
```

Comment: I think you should edit your question to include this information instead of having it in a answer to make it easier on people who might want to help answer the question.  Also, I think you may need to include all the lines from the `/showIncludes` output for one .c/.cpp file - at least up to the error C3861 lines.  What you've shown doesn't indicate that `string.h` was included, but that's probably because it was before wherever you decided to start the copy/paste.

Comment: I've modified my answer based on the infomration you added to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>
#include <cwctype>
#include <ctime>
#include <cio>

using namespace std;

#include "wxcrtbase.h"
#include "wx/chartype.h"

int main(void) {
    return strlen("hey there good buddy!");
}
```

This is the stuff that I hate about c++ the most.

Comment: Are  you sure "<cio>" exists? I get errors and I cannot find it on the internet( google )?

Comment: When I compile YOUR code with cio replaced with io.h, I get the same error messages again

Comment: But, at least its good to see that the problem exists even without my own project B. So, it must be a problem inside wxWidgets?!

Comment: All I was trying to demonstrate was a different ordering of the includes and namespace usage.  <cio> should mean "namespace std { #include <io.h> }".

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  The fix for me had to do with the include order.  Including `string.h` before `stdafx.h` caused the error.  The other way around works.  It seems that the compiler was ignoring `string.h` completely.

Answer (score -1):

I indeed think that you have to include cstdio and cstring (as proposed above), but in this case everything will reside in namespace std, like std::strlen and such...

Comment: I am so tempted to downvote you! How can replacing string.h with cstring solve the problem??!