# Use of undeclared identifier strlen() even after including strlen() Xcode 5

Tags: macos, clang++

i'm compiling an application that uses wxWidgets library. i'm getting an error wxcrtbase.h:667:52: Use of undeclared identifier 'strlen', but i can see wxcrtbase includes string.h in line:35. what might be the reason for this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Header correct, but identifier not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526659/header-correct-but-identifier-not-found)

Comment: thank you. i have some how missed that question.